# adb installs .apk extremely slow from xamarin studio

Tags: android, xamarin, adb

When I build my application in Xamarin Studio it builds fairly quickly. When it gets to installing the .apk on my device it takes about 10 minutes. I have uninstalled Xamarin and I am still having the same issue. It started when I updated to OSX 10.10 Yosemite. Any ideas how I can make it build like it was before i updated.

Comment: Have you tried using 'adb install file.apk'?  I noticed today on my system it gives the download rate.

Comment: I have it takes just as long and it doesn't give me the transfer rate... I hit enter and terminal just sits there.

Comment: Which says that adb is probably the problem.  Does 'adb devices' come right back? Maybe try updating/reinstalling the SDK.  Also, look at:http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26601/usb-transfer-speed-ridiculously-slow

Comment: I've tried uninstalling the SDK and 'adb devices' does come right back. I have discovered that adb only has problems when trying to install .apk files that are fairly big, 20MB or larger.

Comment: That's a big app I think.  I'm still new at android but nothing.  I've written is over 2.5 Mb.  Could you be short on memory?  Have you tried other devices?  I know that the memory used to store apps is not the same as the SDK.  I don't know what kind of optimization Android does with that memory.  Also try 'pushing' something to see if that is faster.